Ensure Gurobi uses callback on all feasible solutions?
I'm try to solve a satisfiability problem on Gurobi with lazy constraints. The issue I'm encountering is, Gurobi will find a valid solution and terminate rather than put the solution into the callback and gain the next set of constraints it must satisfy (I understand not all solutions are put into the callback).
My current approach is to test the solutions once the optimization is complete and then if necessary restart the optimization problem with the additional constraints but this seems rather clunky and wastes time. Is there a better way to avoid this problem?

Can you update your post with the callback code?

Are you using your callback on fractional solutions only? I had this problem before and applied the same callback to integer solutions as well. It looks like if the solution at the end of the root node is integer, gurobi doesn't pass through callbacks for fractional solutions.
Your way of doing it, i.e. adding the constraint yourself and re-optimizing it, is actually one of the two ways JuMP use in their tutorial on callbacks (see https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/algorithms/tsp_lazy_constraints/). And funnily enough, this way out-performs the method using the built-in callback on the problem treated.
